# Implications of removing a Google+ account

Tags: gmail, google, youtube, google-plus

I recently upgraded my semi-throwaway Gmail account to Google+ in order to test the video conferencing abilities of Hangout. I would like to remove this as much as possible. Does *Google+* → *Settings* → *Delete Entire Google Profile* remove **everything** associated with my Google account (including Gmail and Google Voice) or just the Google+ Products?

What happens when I click the button I have selected in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to remove you Google+ information, then I would suggest selecting the option `Delete Google+ Content` - I don't know if deleting your entire Google account will affect login to Gmail, but you can read more about deleting your account on the [help article page](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=32046)

[This is another article](http://www.troublefixers.com/how-to-delete-google-plus-or-google-account-safely-without-deleting-google-or-gmail-account/) that highlights only selecting Google+ content to delete. Don't select the entire account, if anything start with just Google+ content as the first trial step.